# How to get data of a regression line in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I run my `qplot(data, x, y)` and get a smoothing line by adding

```
+ geom_smooth(method=lm)
```

How do you get data about this smoothing line?

Answer (score 2):

You are fitting a linear model, so you can fit the model outside the `qplot` call and look at the fitted values, residuals, etc.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x, data)
names(fit)
summary(fit)
fit$residuals
fit$fitted.values
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by running a linear regression?

```
lm(y~x,data)
```